# Generate a random double between 1 and max in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

How would i generate a random double between 1 and a defined max in c++/cli, ive use random_number_distribution and mersenne twister in the random header before but never in cli, will this work in cli with random or system::random, or are there any similar alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: It is not different, the only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: I plan on trying it but im at work and dont have access to my computer i couldnt find a solution online so i wanted to ask while i had downtime

Comment: So mersenne twister and random_number_distribution work in cli the same way they work in unmanaged c++?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how

```
double randDouble(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}
```

Comment: Im looking for random double not an int

Answer (score 0):

The [`System::Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) class, with its [`NextDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) method is what you want. `NextDouble` will return a double >= 0.0 and < 1.0. So, to return a value between 1 and a max:

```
double RandOneToMax(double max)
{
    Random^ r = ...;
    return (r->NextDouble() * (max - 1)) + 1;
}
```